# DataType Category not understood?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_table("D:\Machine Learning SW\MusicRec\lastfm-dataset-    360K\usersha1-artmbid-artname-plays.tsv", 
                     usecols=[0, 2, 3], 
                     names=['user', 'artist', 'plays'])

# map each artist and user to a unique numeric value
data['user'] = data['user'].astype("category")
data['artist'] = data['artist'].astype("category")


# create a sparse matrix of all the artist/user/play triples
plays = coo_matrix((data['plays'].astype(float), 
               (data['artist'].cat.codes, 
                data['user'].cat.codes)))
```

The dtype of the data is object. How do i typecast it to category?

Comment: Please show a sample of your original dataset to let us help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the type of values in your dataset are object, try the dtype = object option when you read your file:

```
data = pandas.read_table("your_file.tsv", usecols=[0, 2, 3], 
                     names=['user', 'artist', 'plays'],dtype = object)
```

And if it's only for a particular column:

```
data = pandas.read_table("your_file.tsv", usecols=[0, 2, 3], 
                     names=['user', 'artist', 'plays'],dtype = {col_name : object})
```